# Create a custom JPA temporal annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want some of mycoulmns in the JPA entity to take values from database during inserts/updates, i.e from Oracle sys_context, I believe JPA temporal annotation includes database generated timestamps during insert/updates, Is there any way I could create a custom annotation somewhat simailar to this or provide some default values during inserts/updates, can someone give few pointers if you faced this situation.

Answer (score 2):

> I want some of mycoulmns in the JPA entity to take values from database during inserts/updates

Configure the `@Column` to be not insertable and updatable and annotate the field with [`@Generated`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html) (Hibernate specific annotation). By doing so, Hibernate will fetch the value from the database after an insert, update. From the Reference Documentation:

> #### [2.4.3.5. Generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2859)
>
> Some properties are generated at
>   insert or update time by your
>   database. Hibernate can deal with such
>   properties and triggers a subsequent
>   select to read these properties.
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Antenna {
>     @Id public Integer id;
>     @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
>     @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
>     public String longitude;
>
>     @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) @Column(insertable = false)
>     public String latitude;
> }
> ```
>
> Annotate your property as `@Generated`
>   You have to make sure your
>   insertability or updatability does not
>   conflict with the generation strategy
>   you have chosen. When
>   `GenerationTime.INSERT` is chosen, the
>   property must not contains insertable
>   columns, when `GenerationTime.ALWAYS`
>   is chosen, the property must not
>   contains insertable nor updatable
>   columns.
>
> `@Version` properties cannot be
>   `@Generated(INSERT)` by design, it has
>   to be either `NEVER` or `ALWAYS`.